# Laravel Docker On Window Volume mounting

Tags: laravel, docker, github, docker-compose, docker-volume

I setup docker on window and setup Laravel project to run on docker, images are created but unfortunately volume is not mounting. Docker Project https://github.com/wariszargardev/Laravel-Nginx-Docker- project is setup on root. I have tried no of solution but unfortunately to setup on window. Same project with no changes working on Mac M2.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

networks:
    laravel-vpn-network:

services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:stable-alpine
        container_name: nginx
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html
            - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
        depends_on:
            - php
#            - mysql
        networks:
            - laravel-vpn-network

    php:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: php
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
        networks:
            - Laravel-vpn-network
```

**Docker File **

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

EXPOSE 9000
```

**
App.conf**

Root of project in nginx directory conf.d directory inside this app.conf file present

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

This simple template if anyone available to guide me?